# Discrepancy Chi-Squared test of independence in scipy

Tags: chi-squared-test, contingency-tables, scipy

I don't understand the value `scipy.stats.chi2_contingency` is giving me. The expected values seem fine, but the $\chi^2$ value is different from what manual calculation and online calculators give me.

Example data [table](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/128302/319240):

<kbd>Response 1</kbd><kbd>Response 2</kbd>
<kbd>Group 1</kbd>  <kbd>1991</kbd>           <kbd>1647</kbd>           
<kbd>Group 2</kbd>  <kbd>3181</kbd>           <kbd>3761</kbd>

## [scipy.stats.chi2_contingency](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.15.1/reference/generated/scipy.stats.chi2_contingency.html)

This gives expected frequencies `1778.42495274,  1859.57504726, 3393.57504726,  3548.42495274`, which is fine, but $\chi^2=75.4039$ and $p = 3.84 \cdot 10^{-18}$.

## [scipy.stats.power_divergence](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.14.0/reference/generated/scipy.stats.power_divergence.html) and [scipy.stats.mstats.chisquare](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.mstats.chisquare.html)

```
>> scipy.stats.power_divergence([1991, 1647, 3181, 3761], \
              f_exp=[1778.42495274,  1859.57504726, 3393.57504726,  3548.42495274]))
Power_divergenceResult(statistic=75.759843436927866, pvalue=2.4902429621068866e-16)
```

From looking at the `scipy.stats.chi2_contingency` [source code](https://github.com/scipy/scipy/blob/v0.15.1/scipy/stats/contingency.py#L110), this is allegedly what is called, yet when calling it separately as above I am getting a different $\chi^2$ value.

An alternative function yields the same:

```
>> scipy.stats.mstats.chisquare([1991, 1647, 3181, 3761], \
            f_exp=[1778.42495274,  1859.57504726, 3393.57504726,  3548.42495274])
Power_divergenceResult(statistic=75.759843436927866, pvalue=2.4902429621068866e-16)
```

## Manual

From the expected frequencies, the $\chi^2$ value should indeed be

$\chi^2 = \frac{(1991-1778.42)^2}{1778.42} + \frac{(1647-1859.58)^2}{1859.58} + \frac{(3181-3393.58)^2}{3393.58} + \frac{(3761-3548.42)^2}{3548.42} = 75.7598$

## [socscistatistics.com Chi-Square Calculator](http://www.socscistatistics.com/tests/chisquare/Default2.aspx)

Yields the same $\chi^2$ statistic.

**So, my question**: what does the `scipy.stats.chi2_contingency` function do differently, or what am I doing wrong? It should be a Pearson's chi-squared test without Yates correction, but seems to deviate from that definition.

```
>> scipy.__version__
'0.17.0'
```

Comment: The use or lack of use of the Yates correction ought to produce differences of precisely the magnitude you are noting.

Comment: Aha, you are right. I thought I tested it but assumed the correction was not applied by default (i.e. `correction=False`) - my mistake.